# How to share work space in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, share, cvs

I have following problem:

3 people are working on the same Java project and want to share a workspace so we can all work together.  Our computers are connected to a local network, but we want to share the workspace created in one computer.

Comment: Do not, repeat DO NOT, try to share a workspace between machines. It will cause problems and headaches. Sharing projects is supported, as indicated by the answer(s) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is currently the standard tool to use in this case. There are others but I would recommend using it over anything else. It is also free.

http://git-scm.com/

After downloading and installing on each of your machines create a public repository to store the project.

Here is the getting started page:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control

Answer (score 2):

Multiple Eclipse instances would NOT run well on the same "physical" files. Eclipse does not even reload directories when there are modifications. This means, you get trouble if you sync the filesystems.

The best way to work together and share the code is to use some kind of revision control system, i.e:

- git
- SVN
- Mercurial

Comment: I believe eclipse also stories users information like what files you have open and which tab is selected.  This will inevitably get messed with what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RickSmith Maybe I haven't expressed myself well, but I am actually suggesting to use revision control system rather than synchronizing files.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was trying to add to why your answer was correct.  Not only your source files will have problems but also eclipses metafiles.  It must have been me who failed to express myself correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into setting up some kind of version control, like Git, and some hosting service.